# how to get multiple object value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

i have following code i have more then one object in return  how to get these please help check below code and image file

```
 .then(response => {
        this.jobCategories = response.data;
        console.log(response.data);
        this.jobCategories.categories.sort(function(a,b){

          a.child_categories.sort();

           return a.category_name > b.category_name;

        });
        this.selectedCategoryL1 = this.jobCategories.categories[0];
        this.selectedCategoryL2 = this.selectedCategoryL1.child_categories[0];
      });
```

//MY DROP DOWN

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" name="category" id="category" ng-model="postjobcustomerCtrl.selectedCategoryL1" ng-options="category.category_name for category in postjobcustomerCtrl.jobCategories.categories | orderBy:'category_name' track by category.category_name" ng-change="postjobcustomerCtrl.changeChildCategory()" aria-invalid="false" style=""></select>
```

Sub Category

```
<select class="form-control" name="subcategory" id="subcategory" ng-model="postjobcustomerCtrl.selectedCategoryL2" ng-options="option for option in postjobcustomerCtrl.selectedCategoryL1.child_categories | orderBy"></select>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: not exactly clear what your asking for, whats your expected outcome?

Comment: i have drop down selectedcategoryL1, i want show data in this dropdown

Comment: if the above code is in your controller, this. selectedCategoryL1 is no longer the lexical $scope 'this'. you need to set this to a var outside of the method or use $scope. selectedCategoryL1.

Comment: how......... > ??

Comment: Please include data and error messages as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following, I think this is problem.
if the above code is in your controller, this. selectedCategoryL1 is no longer the lexical $scope 'this'. you need to set this to a var outside of the method or use $scope. selectedCategoryL1.

```js
var vm = this;
//or use $scope.selectedCategoryL1


.then(response => {
  this.jobCategories = response.data;
  console.log(response.data);
  this.jobCategories.categories.sort(function(a, b) {

    a.child_categories.sort();

    return a.category_name > b.category_name;

  });
  //or replace vm with $scope.
  vm.selectedCategoryL1 = this.jobCategories.categories[0];
  vm.selectedCategoryL2 = this.selectedCategoryL1.child_categories[0];
});
```

Comment: could you share more of your controller and how your using it in the view

Comment: are you still getting undefined? if your remove your drop down, do you get the error?

Comment: can you show me how you updated your code after I suggested using vm or  $scope.